# What is this weird character I found by smashing my keyboard?

Tags: unicode

While I was smashing my keyboard, it put a character that I haven't seen before. It's really weird, because when I search it, or put it on a text area, the texture just disappears. When I search it, it appears again, but Google just thinks it's a question mark (?).

Here's a photo of the character before being a question mark:

[image: Weird_Character.jpg]

Also, when I put the character in the upper part of Chrome (where the url is), it appears. That's how I got the screenshot...

Here's the character if you want to copy it:

```html
&#127;
```

Or [download this file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/et3exp36n6yi7zf/txt.txt/file) into Notepad.

Comment: I'm guessing it's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character

Comment: Unicode provides characters which "visually represent" control characters. It may be just one of such representation: https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf so U+2421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 0x5453 notes, this is DELETE (U+007F). On Windows you would get this if you held down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and pressed <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> on the numeric keypad.  See [Alt code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) on Wikipedia.